# BASH Reading prompt from GDB

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gdb

My intentions are the following. I am debugging an object file compiled with gcc from a .c script. Lets call this compiled script "foo". When I run the command from my terminal on mac:

```
gdb -q ./foo
```

I get the an output of:

```
Reading symbols from ./foo...Reading symbols from /Users/john/Documents....done.
done.
```

And immediately I get a prompt from the shell looking like so:

```
(gdb) "Shell waiting for my input command here from keyboard"
```

At this point I want to automate the input of certain commands like:
break, list, x/x "symbol in .c file", x/s "symbol in .c file" and many more. For this automation I want to use a little bash script, and so far I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT=$1
gstdbuf -oL gdb -q $SCRIPT |
        while read -r LINE
        do
            echo "$LINE"
        done
```

At the point of executing this bash script, I see the following output on my terminal's shell:

```
Reading symbols from ./foo...Reading symbols from /Users/john/Documents....done.
done.
```

But I do not see the:

```
(gdb) "Shell waiting for my input command here from keyboard"
```

How can I detect this prompt from the gdb process in my shell script in order to be able to automate the commands I want instead of inputting them manually?

Many Thanks!

Comment: please remove the 'c' tag from here.

Comment: Perhaps you want the "expect" package.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why some people on stack-overflow need to be so obnoxious regarding non-important details about questions. If I put the "C" tag in the question was because there are lots of people who know C and use bash frequently, so they would perhaps guide me in some way. Aren't we all here to help each other and learn anyways? @Serge

Comment: @SebastianSerrano: yes and no. Understand that this is not a standard help site but rather a question and answer site where both questions and answers are moderated by the community, and where the goal is to create questions and answers that are helpful to current *and future* visitors. If you mis-tag your questions, you will annoy both C experts who come to it expecting it to be a C question, and future wanna-be C experts who expect to learn something C related in the question. The request to remove the improper tag was appropriate and hardly "obnoxious".

Comment: @SebastianSerrano I've posted an answer yesterday. Does it work for you? I'm missing feedback on this

Comment: I understand where you are coming from and it guided me in the right direction, even though my final solution wasn't exactly the one you provided. Thanks a lot for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file `.gdbinit` and put the initial commands there. `gdb` will execute them on startup if you added the following line to `$HOME/.gdbinit`:

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/project/.gdbinit
```

Now you can place commands into */path/to/project/.gdbinit*, like this:

```
break main
run --foo=bar
```